# Hashing functions checks for argon2id even when driver set to bcrypt

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, hash, bcrypt, argon2-ffi

I am upgrading an older project to Laravel 5.7. User passwords were hashed with `bcrypt` previously. On the new setup hashing driver is set to `bcrypt` in the config file but still getting the following error.

```
local.ERROR: This password does not use the Argon2id algorithm. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): This password does not use the Argon2id algorithm. at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/Argon2IdHasher.php:20
```

`Auth::attempt()` returns `true` but *login* is not persisted on redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read a few posts about people having issues with this. Perhaps this github issue will help you out, they're having similar problems: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25586

Edit: This may help also, https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24162

Answer (score 0):

use

`Hash::make($request->password);`,

when  you hash  your  password. it can help